# when I update module from odoo15 to odoo16 gets this error below:

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-15, odoo-16

This error below happened when I try to Install apps to odoo16

File "/mnt/extra-addons/ks_list_view_manager/controllers/lvm_controller.py", line 13, in  class LvmController(DataSet, http.Controller): TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
at makeErrorFromResponse (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10383:19) (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:34)
at XMLHttpRequest. (http://134.122.110.222:10016/web/assets/debug/web.assets_backend.js:10436:27) (/web/static/src/core/network/rpc_service.js:87)